# Can't connect to oracle remotelly

Tags: oracle-11g

I've been trying to install oracle in my home for more than a month now, but I still having some issues.

Currently I have the server installed and running on a dedicated Win2k8R2 virtual machine.
The installation seems alright. Locally it works the way it's supposed to do.

However I can't logon remotely in sqlplus/sqldeveloper/Visual Studio or whatsoever.

Initially I was getting a ORA-12514 error. After I corrected the TNS I got stuck on this situation whenever I try to logon:

```
C:\>sqlplus gama@main

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Jan 17 09:22:43 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:
```

The connection get stucked after I give the password and hit enter.
There is no error message. I tough that I would receive a timeout, but no matter how long I wait, nothing happens (yesterday, it took a 3 hour skyrim session before I give up and hit CTRL+C)

Again, I can connect locally and also I have no firewall problems (I've even disabled the firewall in client and server). The client machine can connect to the server via Remote desktop. The connection to Oracle is established as I can confirm in `netstat` and finally, here's the output of the `LSNRCTL services` for the server while in the 'stuck state':

```
LSNRCTL> services
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:0 refused:0
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "MAIN.WIN2k8-ORACLE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "main", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "DEDICATED" established:1 refused:0 state:ready
         LOCAL SERVER
Service "MAINXDB.WIN2k8-ORACLE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "main", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
    Handler(s):
      "D000" established:0 refused:0 current:0 max:1022 state:ready
         DISPATCHER <machine: WIN2K8-ORACLE, pid: 1712>
         (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=WIN2k8-ORACLE)(PORT=49160))
The command completed successfully
```

Note the service MAIN.WIN2k8-ORACLE has 1 established connection.

I do have some experience developing for Oracle but this is the first time I try to install it.

Thanks in advance.

====EDIT======
Folow my tnsnames.ora:

```
MAIN =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <MY SERVER'S IP>)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = MAIN.WIN2k8-ORACLE)
    )
  )
```

Comment: Please update with your tnsnames file.

Answer (score 0):

Please post output of lsnrctl services. You can try to bounce DB and listener.
You can also try to add UR=A setting to your tnsnames.ora

...
( SERVICE_NAME=srv1 )
( UR=A )
...